# Why doesn't Pytest ignore warnings?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, warnings

When I run tests, I'm getting DeprecationWarnings that are reported by Pytest. I would like Pytest to ignore these warnings and not report them.

I've put this in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
filterwarnings = [
    #'ignore:The distutils package is deprecated:DeprecationWarning',
    'ignore::DeprecationWarning',
]
```

However, I'm still seeing the warnings:

```
============================================================================================= warnings summary =============================================================================================
../../home/ramrachum/.venvs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/monitoring/video_recorder.py:9
  /home/ramrachum/.venvs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/monitoring/video_recorder.py:9: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Us
e setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
    import distutils.spawn

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
======================================================================================= 2 passed, 1 warning in 4.48s =======================================================================================
```

I run Pytest in the folder where the `pyproject.toml` file is. I'm sure that Pytest is reading the file, because when I put the wrong type quote on it, `pytest` complained about the error and wouldn't even run.

I also tried just putting a simple `'ignore'` in that configuration file, and also later a simple `'error'` but Pytest still produces the same output, showing the warning as a warning.

What's wrong here? **How can I get Pytest to ignore these warnings?**

Comment: If this is helpful, here's some output with `--full-trace` and `assert 0` injected right before the warning: https://gist.github.com/cool-RR/a5412cad14d06b7f24675e0e9aa8e347

Comment: As far as I can tell, your configuration is correct and works in my test project so the problem is due to something else.

Comment: Could you try specifying the filtering in command line? `pytest -W "ignore::DeprecationWarning" ...`

Comment: Thanks @tmt. I tried it now with `pytest -W "ignore::DeprecationWarning" ` and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? [Source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html#deprecationwarning-and-pendingdeprecationwarning)

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning
```

## Update

As it looks like the warning happens while importing the `import distutils.spawn` at the begin of your file, try this:

```py
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    import distutils.spawn

# Other imports an rest of file...
```

or suppres all warnings (not recomented):

Comment: I'm assuming you meant I should put this text in a `pytest.ini` file rather than the `pyproject.toml` file I was using. Tell me if you meant otherwise. I copy-pasted this text there, but still I'm getting the same problem described in the original question: The warning is shown rather than suppressed.

Comment: I'm guess the same command also works in a pyproject.toml. How do you run the test, which command do you use? Can you be sure that your pyproject.toml is taken in account?

Comment: And have you tried [some other wasys](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html) like the `-W` flag or `with pytest.warns(Warning):` ?

Comment: "Can you be sure that your pyproject.toml is taken in account?" Yes, when I had an error in it it showed an error message and refused to run.
"How do you run the test, which command do you use?" I use a plain `pytest` command on the shell.

Comment: "And have you tried some other ways like the -W flag or with pytest.warns(Warning):" I tried the `-W` flag (see comments on question), didn't help. I can't try the `with` thing because the warning happens during import.

Comment: I recommend trying 2 more things to narrow in the problem: 
1. Make a wider exeption on `Warning` (all warnings, not only `DeprecationWarning`)
2. Make a test with your own warning `warnings.warn("MyTest", DeprecationWarning)` to see if it also is not ignored, or it works in general but is a problem with the distutils-library only

Comment: Your first suggestion (changing to `Warning`) didn't change the output I get. Your second suggestion is a great idea. Indeed, when I send my own warning, Pytest does handle it correctly (i.e. show it as an error or ignore it, depending on which settings I choose.)

This leads me to believe that the problem is that the original warning is sent during setup time, which causes Pytest to treat it differently. But I'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: I see two possible ways: 1. Try to put the `import distutils.spawn` not at top of your file, but as first line in every test function you need it 2. Ignore warnings [like this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#overriding-the-default-filter), but make sure you place the code bevor the `import distutils.spawn` at the begin of your file. Also, see my updated solution

Comment: I tried your updated solution. It didn't work, and even if it did, it wouldn't be right for me, because that code is in a library that I import. (That's the only reason I haven't removed the import.)

Comment: So? Then put the import of *"library that I import"* inside the `with`? Anyway, I think you have now enough different solution how to suppress warnings if you really want to do so. Now you just have to put it in the right place. I can not help you with that if I don't see the full code

Comment: "So? Then put the import of "library that I import" inside the with?" I tried something like that, but then I still get the warnings. Thanks for your help, clearly this is a problem with Pytest.